# How to set ViewBag for _Layout in MVC4 using async in every action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

The usecase is simple. Info for logged in user is displayed in _Layout.cshtml. That info needs to be refreshed every time.

I found two ways to do that

- Have `BaseController` and in its `OnActionExecuting` method set `ViewBag.UserInfo = ...;` which is later used in _Layout.cshtml
- In `_Layout.cshtml` do `@{Html.RenderAction("GlobalUserInfo", "UserInfo");}`

The problem is that these two ways fail miserably with deadlocks or exceptions if UserInfo is returned from an async `public async Task<UserInfo>GetUserInfo(){...}` method.

So the question is this: How to set ViewBag properties on every action when data is retrieved using async/await.

Comment: Why don't you create a Helper to share this information on `_Layout`?

Comment: @felipe-oriani The problem is not to come up with "yet another  solution" to show some data globally. The problem is to do it with async/await. Helpers won't save me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC is not quite fully `async`-friendly, particularly with filters.

You could write your own `RenderAsyncAction` extension method or duplicate the code in all your `async` actions.

Alternatively, you could attempt a bit of a hack. I describe on my blog [why using `Result` in ASP.NET can deadlock](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), but there's a workaround: use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on *every* `await` in `GetUserInfo`.

Then you can define a synchronous wrapper:

```
public UserInfo GetUserInfoBlocking()
{
  return GetUserInfo().Result;
}
```

You should be able to use `GetUserInfoBlocking` in `OnActionExecuting` or `RenderAction`.

Please note the side effects:

- This approach uses *multiple* threads per request, so this will *decrease* scalability. The pure `async` approach uses multiple requests per thread, so it *increases* scalability.
- Any exceptions from `GetUserInfo` will be wrapped in an `AggregateException`, so be sure your logging will capture the `InnerException` details or you'll get meaningless errors in your logs.

It's definitely best to use `async` all the way down instead of blocking like this. But sometimes MVC doesn't leave you a choice (hopefully this will change in the future).

Comment: I am already using `OnActionExecuting` with `.Result` and `.ConfigureAwait(false)` all the way down the stack but it just feels like an ugly hack, hense this question. Thank you for the answer!